# In RecyclerView.Adapter, notifyItemChanged doesn't always call onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm dealing with a rather annoying bug where multiple (identical) calls of notifyItemChanged() only trigger onBindViewHolder() sometimes. I call notifyItemChanged like this:

```
public void updateData(Data stuff) {

  // Update data.
  int index = findIndexOfChangedItem(stuff);

  // Using or adding notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't help.
  notifyItemChanged(index);
}
```

And onBindViewHolder is pretty simple.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder called for position " + position);
    holder.setData(myList.get(position));
}
```

The problem I observe is that when updateData() is called many times (sometimes frequently, many times within a second), some of the updates are dropped. But it does go through half the time so I know that the basic implementation somewhat works.

I've looked at all the obvious things, like making sure the index is correct and notifyItemChanged() is actually getting called. Also, interestingly, if I add my own custom observer:

```
private RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver obs = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
      Log.d(TAG, "Observed state change in custom observer.");
      super.onChanged();
    }
  };
```

I see that the custom observer gets triggered **every single time**!

Is there any reason why RecyclerView.Adapter's onBindViewHolder gets skipped sometimes, and is there a way to get around it?

**Edit**

I wonder if this is due to the `androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper`'s `onItemRangeChanged` only returning `true` if there's exactly one thing to update:

```
/**
 * @return True if updates should be processed.
 */
boolean onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload) {
    if (itemCount < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    mPendingUpdates.add(obtainUpdateOp(UpdateOp.UPDATE, positionStart, itemCount, payload));
    mExistingUpdateTypes |= UpdateOp.UPDATE;
    return mPendingUpdates.size() == 1;
}
```

Then, if I'm adding an update while one is already pending, this returns `false` and my update is dropped.

Comment: If the item changed isnt in view it isnt going to get called because it does not need to

Comment: If the item of RecyclerView is not visible on screen then onBindViewHolder will not trigged unless until that particular get visible again after scroll.

Comment: This method `onBindViewHolder` won't be called if the index of the item changed is not currently bound to one of the reusable `ViewHolder` instances. This is normal behaviour - why update a view if not visible, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @yash786 In my case, I'm not scrolling at all, and my list only has one item, and the view is always visible on my screen. So is it possible that if the previous update hasn't finished, or somehow an update briefly hides a holder, that a new call to onBindViewHolder gets skipped because it thinks it's somehow hidden?

Comment: @MarkKeen So is it fair to say that, because I'm updating very quickly, the item changed sometimes gets unbound from a ViewHolder instance (during an update), and when a new update is made during this time, onBindViewHolder() doesn't get called? That would make sense. The reason I would still need the update to get called is that my ViewHolder is stateful, and I need to capture all transitions to show in the UI. (It's a list showing steps completed, and if I don't get an update, that step shows as incomplete, even if it was actually done.)

Comment: Are you always using the main thread here?

Comment: @MarkKeen Yes I'm always running on the main thread for this.

Comment: Without looking at the`RecyclerView` source code I couldn't say if there is some sort of debounce on binding new data. If you have to update an item so often it would make more sense to do that work in the holder, subscribing to events there - although discouraged seems valid for this usecase here

Comment: Thanks! OK, yes, updating the holder directly seems to work, so I will do that instead of via the adapter and notifyItemChanged().

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and discovered that `notifyItemChanged` that happen after `onBindViewHolder`, but before bound view had chance to be actually attached in `onViewAttachedToWindow` are dropped. IMO invalidation of data shouldn't depend on view state - it's another (presentation) layer, so it's most likely a bug.

I filled a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170125522

The workaround I use for now - just track for which view you called notifyItemChanged and check in `onViewAttachedToWindow` if `onBindViewHolder` was called for it. If it wasn't then call `notifyItemChanged` there.